# How to conditionally append an element in a scoped Vue Component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I am trying to create a Component for titles that can be edited when they get double clicked.
The Component takes the h-tag that should be used and the title as props and should produce a normal h-tag, that turns into an input field once double clicked.
This already works if there is only one title on the page, however once there are multiple Components used on one page, it breaks as the Component is not scoped properly. But I can't figure out how.
Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="edit-on-click">
    <input
      :class="sizeClass"
      type="text"
      v-if="edit"
      v-model="editedTitle"
      @blur="finishEdit"
      @keyup.enter="finishEdit"
      v-focus="true"
    />
    <span v-show="!edit" @dblclick.prevent="edit = true"></span>
  </div>
</template>
```

The mounted hook I can't figure out how to scope:

```
  mounted() {
    let node = document.createElement(this.size); // Takes h-tag (h1, h2 etc.)
    let titleText = document.createTextNode(this.finalTitle); // Takes title

    node.appendChild(titleText);
    node.classList.add("editable-title");

    // This breaks the code once there are multiple components in the document
    document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].appendChild(node);
  },
```

How can I scope this in an efficient way? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I ended up including all the different title options (h1-h5) in the template and enabling them with v-if statements. Would still be interesting to know if there is a way to scope this component more efficiently.

Comment: Next time add code minimal code example (Include data). Very hard to answer like this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with Vue, you'll probably want to avoid creating DOM elements the "native" way whenever possible, as you might run into race condition where Vue is unaware of the existence of these elements which you probably want be reactive at some point in time (in your case, the `<span>` double-clicking).

What you could do instead, is perhaps to dynamically "switch between" these different headings with this `<component>` and the `v-bind:is` prop. Consider the following example:

```js
Vue.component('EditableHeading', {
  template: '#editable-heading',

  props: {
    size: {
      type: String,
      default: 'h1'
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      editing: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    confirm(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value);
      this.close();
    },
    start() {
      this.editing = true;
      
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$el.querySelector('input[type="text"]').select();
      });
    },
    close() {
      this.editing = false;
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    titleList: [],
    text: 'New Title',
    size: 'h3'
  }),

  methods: {
    addNewTitle() {
      this.titleList.push({
        text: this.text,
        size: this.size
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.edit-on-click {
  user-select: none;
}

.heading-size {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 24px;
}

p.info {
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  color: brown;
  padding: 4px 5px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <editable-heading 
    v-for="(title, index) of titleList" :key="index" 
    v-model="title.text" 
    :size="title.size">
  </editable-heading>

  <div>
    <label>
      Heading size: 
      <input v-model="size" class="heading-size" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Title: 
      <input v-model="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button @click="addNewTitle()">Add new title</button>
  </div>

  <p class="info">
    [double-click]: Edit <br />
    [enter]: Confirm <br />
    [esc/mouseleave]: Cancel
  </p>
</div>

<script id="editable-heading" type="text/x-template">
  <div class="edit-on-click">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      v-if="editing" 
      :value="value" 
      @blur="close" 
      @keydown.enter="confirm" 
      @keydown.esc="close" />

    <component :is="size" v-else @dblclick="start">{{value}}</component>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sure seems like a cleaner way than resorting to vanilla JS.